# Filtering & Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, accordion

I have developed a Website in Wordpress and there is training calendar in it, its working fine in Desktop Version. But for mobile version we are hiding some content and added accordion.

You can check the below link : (**I have removed this link as my issue is resolved**)

My issue is that, in mobile version, the accordion is working but the content is overlapping. :(

What is wrong or can be done for resolving this issue?? I have tired a lot of things :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded with this query, i have used Bootstrap Table expandable with MultiFilter.

Thanks you for your support

You can download MultiFilter here : [Click Here](https://github.com/tommyp/multifilter)